# Angular ng-click dynamic content

Tags: angularjs

Ok i have no idea how to generate dynamic a links. Im creating a dynamic navbar

```
<div ng-repeat="elem in elements">
<div ng-class="{ 'active' : anchor=={{elem}} }">
<a ng-click="anchor = elem">{{elem}}</a>
</div>
```

The problem is ng-click takes an expression. I cant pass there dynamic content from elem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<a ng-click="anch($index)">{{elem}}</a>
```

In controller

```
$scope.anch = functin(index) {
    $scope.anchor = elements[index];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">
    <a ng-click="upload_variant_image()">{{item.name}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your `elem` to controller using by

```
 ng-click="action(elem)"
```

Please see sample below

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('fCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.elements = [1, 2, 3, 4];

  $scope.action = function(elem) {
    $scope.anchor = elem

  }

  $scope.anchor = 1;

});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="fCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="elem in elements">
      <div ng-class="{ 'active' : anchor=={{elem}} }">
        <a ng-click="action(elem)">{{elem}}</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```